# Error while install gcc49 in Ubuntu by using linuxbrew

Tags: linux, gcc, homebrew, mpfr, linuxbrew

I want to install the latest `gcc49` in a Ubuntu Linux, and I am familiar with `Homebrew` in Mac, so I would like to use the Linux version of it, i.e., `Linuxbrew`. So I installed `Linuxbrew` and typed

```
$ brew install gcc49
```

The dependencies `gmp4`, `mpfr2` and etc. will be installed first. I have added a `if OS.mac?` condition in `gmp4` so it can be installed successfully, but when installing `mpfr2` (also added the condition), the `make check` failed with the error:

```
...
/tmp/mpfr2-i5YD/mpfr-2.4.2/tests/.libs/lt-tpow_all: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
FAIL: tpow_all
=======================
148 of 148 tests failed
=======================
```

As you can see, the tests can not find `libgmp.so.3` which is just installed. But `gmp4` is keg only since it will conflict with gmp in main repository.

But the configure options are set with the correct location of `gmp4`:

```
./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/home/dongli/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mpfr2/2.4.2 --with-gmp=/home/dongli/.linuxbrew/opt/gmp4
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, that is the environment has been reset after each `system` call in Ruby formula. So we need to set the correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as

```
if OS.linux?
  ENV["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "#{Formula["..."].opt_prefix}/lib:...:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
end
```

so that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` persists during the build processes.

Answer (score 0):

You think you are doing it wrong by insisting on a third-party scripting solution that is not native to the OS.

There are *prebuilt versions* of gcc et al *provided by the same maintainers* in [this PPA on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test). These are previews / testreleases of what will be in the next Ubuntu releases.

Comment: I prefer a unified solution to install some missing packages (not only gcc49) in Linux (not only Ubuntu), and `linuxbrew` seems to be promising. Thanks for your information!

Comment: Whatever you prefer -- but doing dependencies well *and* across distros is ... nearly impossible. I prefer to live in one well-managed universe, and Debian (and Ubuntu) has served me very well for close to two decades.

Comment: Well, in my world, people always use different Linux distros, and so many annoying dependency problems come up. In `linuxbrew`, I can contribute formulas so that things just need to be done once.